# how to process 15 million of rows in csv file using python with high speed?

Tags: python, csv, google-colaboratory

[image]

I have 15 millions of rows in a csv file with two columns(student ID, Question ID), each student answer more than one question, so you will find same Student ID many times. and another csv file with 187000 rows and two columns(Student ID, Gender), I want to add a new column in the first csv file named "Gender" which represents the gender of 15 millions student (even if student id is duplicate)
I try this code using colaboratory(GPU runtime type), the session was crashed after 3:40 hours.
so what I will do to avoid this, and to perform high speed?

for reading data it takes around 7 sec

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.read_csv('/content/drive/MyDrive/file1.csv')

dg=pd.read_csv('/content/drive/MyDrive/file2.csv')
```

but the problem in processing :

```
df['Gender']=range(0,15000000)

for i in range(len(df.StudentId)):

  for k in range(len(dg.StudentId)):

    if df.StudentId[i] == dg.StudentId[k]:

      df.Gender[i]=dg.Gender[k]
```

Comment: simple answer: do not use loops but vectorial code. Now for the specifics, you should provide an example of your data and the matching output

Comment: You can use dask for loading: https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/generated/dask.dataframe.read_csv.html

Comment: Why are you looping over the dataframe like that?

Comment: I add an image describe what I need, please see it

Answer (score 0):

Try to merge the columns based on the column student ID.

1. Load in the csv files with pandas (https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)

Should look something likes this:

```py
import pandas as pd
df_1 = pd.read_csv('/path/to/csv1.csv')
df_2 = pd.read_csv('/path/to/csv2.csv')
```

2. Merge the two dataframes (https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)

```py
df_all = df_1.merge(df_2, left_on='student ID', right_on='student ID')
df_all.to_csv('/path/to/new_csv.csv')
```

Also a note: try to avoid iterating over rows as much as possible. Iterating is one of the biggest performance killers. Most of the times, you can find specific built in functions that do just what you want way faster.

Comment: I'd rather suggest dask to multiprocess the work.